# window.location not working with uploading data

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

```
<p id="time_out12">100</p>



var time_out=100;
function myCounter()
{
    if(time_out<=100 && time_out>0){
document.getElementById("time_out12").innerHTML = --time_out;
}
    else 
    { 
location.assign("update.php");
    //window.location = "update.php"} //tried this both(working now)
}
}



setInterval(myCounter,1000);
```

So basically i created a 100 seconds timeout function such that after 100 seconds it will update the database with some data that the user input-ed in this php. 
However after that 100 seconds run out, the page doesnt move and keeps having the refreshing sign. I tried manually moving to update.php with a button and it works. But both location.assign and window.location doesnt work. It just hangs at this page..

*I changed the setInterval to 3000 which is calling the myCounter function every 3 seconds, and it works now* I figured that it takes a longer time than 1 second to upload the data. So now my counter -1 every 3 seconds which is not what i want. helpp thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use window.location="update.php"